# How can I make my SQLite file compressable, or tell InstallShield not to bother trying to compress it?

Tags: sqlite, compression, installshield, installshield-le

I've got a small utility that I'm trying to create an installer for to make it a tad easier (and more sheeny-shiny ("professional looking") for people to download and install.

I'm using the free/trial version on InstallShield that is available when using Visual Studio.

I only added three files to the InstallShield wizard: the .exe itself, the .exe's .config file, and the app's sqlite file.

On trying to rebuild the install app, though, I get:

```
-1501: Could not compress "C:\axX&SpaceProjects\FauxDuolingo\Multilingual\bin\x86\Release\multilingual.sqlite" into "C:\axX&SpaceProjects\FauxDuolingo\MultilingualSetup\MultilingualSetup\Express\SingleImage\DiskImages\DISK1\Data1.cab"
```

2-clicking that err msg in Visual Studio's Error List conjures up the page from "Flexera Software Customer Community" (purveyors of InstallShield):

[image]

Is there a way to tell InstallShield, "Never mind - don't compress the SQLite file" or is there some other workaround to make it compressable?

Note: As you can see in the scream shot, this bug has been documented for exactly one year, so you'd think there'd be a resolution by now.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the size of the compressed file; it means that the source file cannot be read or that the target file cannot be created.

Comment: No, I wouldn't think that it did.

Comment: I strongly suspect the **&** character in the path name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQLite manager or DB Browser is open while trying to build with the installshield. Close all open SQLite browser and rebuild installshield. It will build. The size of the file does not matter. I experienced same thing, this solved it.